# Edit anonymous object passed into IUrlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core's [`UrlHelperExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/UrlHelperExtensions.cs) is not that useful, because it only accepts `object` for route values, so I can't add/remove/merge route values. Before Core the equivalent in `UrlHelper` had an overload that took a `RouteValueDictionary`, which made it easy.

So I have a method that performs routing. It receives `object routeValues`, I want to add to it, and then pass to `IUrlHelper.Action(...)`.

I can convert from `object` to `RouteValueDictionary`, but not back to anonymous `object`. Maybe there's another way?

```
public string GenerateOrderRoute(object routeValues = null)
{
  var newRouteValues = //...I want to add/remove/merge to routeValues
  // e.g. I want to add an area 
  return _urlHelper.Action("details", "orders", newRouteValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, but it uses dynamic, which I don't like. If you spot problems with this approach please let me know. And if there is a better/different way then please let me know.

```
public string GenerateOrderRoute(object routeValues = null)
{
  // here I merge given route values with some of my own
  var dict = (routeValues != null) ? new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues) : new RouteValueDictionary();
  dict.Add("area", "commercial");
  dict.Add("foo", "bar");

  var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
  var expandoDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)expandoObject;
  foreach (var keyValuePair in dict)
  {
    expandoDictionary.Add(keyValuePair);
  }

  return _urlHelper.Action("details", "orders", expandoDictionary);
}
```